# What are the SharePoint Server 2010 installation requirements?

Tags: sharepoint, installation, sharepoint-2010, requirements

What are the SharePoint Server 2010 installation requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2010 from Technet

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Hardware and software requirements (SharePoint Server 2010)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The important part to remember is that SharePoint 2010 is 64-bit only.